# using gstreamer to correct lens distortion

Tags: gstreamer, distortion, imx8

Thank you for your answer.

Actually i am working on a module based on NXP imx8 processor. ( linux)
The module includes also two microdisplays which are managed by MachXO2
fpga. Data or images displayed in the microdisplays come from hdmi input.

I have lenses in front of each microdispaly, so we see deformations.

Firstly i thougth that the deformations seen come from
the source ( hdmi video input) thas is why i was looking for a way to
capture the HDMI video input and apply cameracalibte and cameraundistort
filters to it.

Then i realized that the deformations are due to lenses placed in front
of each microdisplay. When i removed them i didn't see any distortion.
The issue or the question : is there  any way to correct this distortion
using gstreamer elements  while keeping my optic (lenses).

I tried to be clear so that you could understand my issue and you could help
me.

Best regards

Comment: never heard of stuff like this.. but what about https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/frei0r/frei0r-filter-lens-correction.html?gi-language=c  .. maybe you will need to compile the gst-plugins-bad package with frei0r support (its not standardly bundled there in Linux distributions)

Comment: Thanks @nayana for your answer. Do you have an idea about wish plugin i could use to capture video from the microdispaly before aplying  ```frei0r-filter-lens-correction``` filter. V4l2src would not work in my case since i don't have a webcam in my card, do you have any suggestion please.

Comment: no idea about the hdmi capture.. I just remember that blackmagic decklink cards have GStreamer element for easy video grabbing (but this apparently does not apply to your obviously embedded NXP system you use).. however if you have other means of intercepting the video you may just pass it to GStreamer via appsrc, then set correct format accordingly (videoparse) and then feed it back so it can go out to the displays. Or you could just use libfrei0r directly. For this you would have to have deep knowledge about the hw implementation.no idea what you use for the system etc.This will not be easy.

Comment: Thank you @nayana your indications was very helpfull. Please i have an othe issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66256368/using-gstreamer-cameraundistort-plugin-with-calculated-distortion-coefficient)  , i don't know if have some ideas that could help me.Thank you