# Using gstreamer cameraundistort plugin with calculated distortion coefficient

Tags: gstreamer, distortion

How can i use distortion coefficient
already calculated using a specific python code  ( `dist [[7.33183864e+03 1.52395233e-01 2.53983049e+00 2.20587897e+00 2.61869010e-06]]` ) with cameraundistort plugin.

I have seen the following example pipeline in the documentation :

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src ! videoconvert ! cameraundistort settings=  !  autovideosink
```

But i dindn't get what kind of argument i should give to settings , is this
where i should put my calculated distortion coefficient or my matrix?

Answer (score 3):

New answer:

I eventually found how to do this from the command line. You will need to edit the values in the DATA variable with your own matrix values:

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04. You should see a distorted videotestsrc when compared to running the standard `gst-launch-1.0 -vv videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

```sh
DATA="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><opencv_storage><cameraMatrix type_id=\"opencv-matrix\"><rows>3</rows><cols>3</cols><dt>f</dt><data>2.85762378e+03 0. 1.93922961e+03 0. 2.84566113e+03 1.12195850e+03 0. 0. 1.</data></cameraMatrix><distCoeffs type_id=\"opencv-matrix\"><rows>5</rows><cols>1</cols><dt>f</dt><data>-6.14039421e-01 4.00045455e-01 1.47132971e-03 2.46772077e-04 -1.20407566e-01</data></distCoeffs></opencv_storage>"

gst-launch-1.0 -vv videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! cameraundistort settings="$DATA" ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Original analysis:

I am trying to find the answer to this too.

Based on the following code here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/-/blob/324e55a3cdd7c6cef24356fd626deee5fba343df/ext/opencv/gstcameracalibrate.cpp

There is a snippet:

```cpp
/* set settings property */
g_free (calib->settings);
calib->settings =
camera_serialize_undistort_settings (calib->cameraMatrix,
calib->distCoeffs);
```

which leads us here to this function: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/-/blob/324e55a3cdd7c6cef24356fd626deee5fba343df/ext/opencv/camerautils.cpp

```cpp
gchar *
camera_serialize_undistort_settings (cv::Mat & cameraMatrix,
    cv::Mat & distCoeffs)
{
  cv::FileStorage fs (".xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE + cv::FileStorage::MEMORY);
  fs << "cameraMatrix" << cameraMatrix;
  fs << "distCoeffs" << distCoeffs;
  std::string buf = fs.releaseAndGetString ();

  return g_strdup (buf.c_str ());
}
```

In order to find out what the output of this looks like I wrote the following  code:

```cpp
//
// g++ -o out main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4 glib-2.0`
//
// https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/-/blob/324e55a3cdd7c6cef24356fd626deee5fba343df/ext/opencv/camerautils.cpp
//

#include <glib.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

gchar *
camera_serialize_undistort_settings (cv::Mat & cameraMatrix,
    cv::Mat & distCoeffs)
{
  cv::FileStorage fs (".xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE + cv::FileStorage::MEMORY);
  fs << "cameraMatrix" << cameraMatrix;
  fs << "distCoeffs" << distCoeffs;
  std::string buf = fs.releaseAndGetString ();

  return g_strdup (buf.c_str ());
}

int main() {

    float camera_matrix_data[9] = { 2.8576236805989838e+03, 0.0, 1.9392296211154603e+03,
            0.0, 2.8456611938133528e+03, 1.1219585111073625e+03, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0 };

    cv::Mat camera_matrix = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, camera_matrix_data);

    float dist_coefficients_data[5] = {-6.1403941690071129e-01, 4.0004545823187132e-01,
            1.4713297080556295e-03, 2.4677208656274745e-04,
            -1.2040756970288242e-01};

    cv::Mat dist_coefficients = cv::Mat(5, 1, CV_32F, dist_coefficients_data);
    
    std::cout << camera_serialize_undistort_settings(camera_matrix, dist_coefficients);

    return 0;
}
```

and I got this as an output, which as far as I can tell is valid for consumption by the `camera_deserialize_undistort_settings()` function:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<cameraMatrix type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>f</dt>
  <data>
    2.85762378e+03 0. 1.93922961e+03 0. 2.84566113e+03 1.12195850e+03 0.
    0. 1.</data></cameraMatrix>
<distCoeffs type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>5</rows>
  <cols>1</cols>
  <dt>f</dt>
  <data>
    -6.14039421e-01 4.00045455e-01 1.47132971e-03 2.46772077e-04
    -1.20407566e-01</data></distCoeffs>
</opencv_storage>
```

Unfortunately I cannot overcome the final stumbling block of feeding this to the command line.

edit:

Non command line solution:

Hopefully the following will help somebody - it's a bit hacked together due to time constraints. Basically I gave up on the command line and found an example of how to run a gstreamer pipeline through code. I hacked in the pipeline and was able to feed the parameters in.

## Calibration

```c
//
// g++ play.cpp -o play `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0 opencv4`
//

#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


//
// USB Webcam
//
const char *string2 = " \
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! cameraundistort name=undist ! cameracalibrate name=cal ! ximagesink \
";


gchar *
camera_serialize_undistort_settings (cv::Mat & cameraMatrix,
    cv::Mat & distCoeffs)
{
  cv::FileStorage fs (".xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE + cv::FileStorage::MEMORY);
  fs << "cameraMatrix" << cameraMatrix;
  fs << "distCoeffs" << distCoeffs;
  std::string buf = fs.releaseAndGetString ();

  return g_strdup (buf.c_str ());
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  gchar value[100] = {0};

  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstElement *filesrc;
  GstMessage *msg;
  GstBus *bus;
  GError *error = NULL;

  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  pipeline = gst_parse_launch (string2, &error);



  if (!pipeline) {
    g_print ("Parse error: %s\n", error->message);
    exit (1);
  }



  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);

  /* wait until we either get an EOS or an ERROR message. Note that in a real
   * program you would probably not use gst_bus_poll(), but rather set up an
   * async signal watch on the bus and run a main loop and connect to the
   * bus's signals to catch certain messages or all messages */
  msg = gst_bus_poll (bus, (GstMessageType) ( GST_MESSAGE_EOS | GST_MESSAGE_ERROR ), -1);

  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS: {
      g_print ("EOS\n");
      break;
    }
    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
      GError *err = NULL; /* error to show to users                 */
      gchar *dbg = NULL;  /* additional debug string for developers */

      gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &dbg);
      if (err) {
          filesrc = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (pipeline), "undist");

        gchar *val;

        g_object_get (filesrc, "settings", &val, NULL);
        
        g_print("Data:\n");

        g_print ("%s", val);

        g_object_unref (filesrc);

        g_print("\nDone\n");

        g_printerr ("ERROR: %s\n", err->message);
        g_error_free (err);
      }
      if (dbg) {
        g_printerr ("[Debug details: %s]\n", dbg);
        g_free (dbg);
      }
    }
    default:
      g_printerr ("Unexpected message of type %d", GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg));
      break;
  }
  gst_message_unref (msg);


  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  gst_object_unref (bus);

  return 0;
}
```

You calibrate as normal using a checkerboard as per the opencv recommended way.

On closing, this will give an output such as this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<cameraMatrix type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    3.3860583405334381e+02 0. 2.9082938038777263e+02 0.
    3.3860583405334381e+02 1.5389814447354675e+02 0. 0. 1.</data></cameraMatrix>
<distCoeffs type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>5</rows>
  <cols>1</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    -7.3120392823523372e-01 6.2624904277006888e-01
    -1.0205399762451621e-02 5.1857216532169093e-03
    -2.0130033675444331e-01</data></distCoeffs>
</opencv_storage>
```

You can then put this in to another program and load it as such:

## Running

```c
//
// g++ play.cpp -o play `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0 opencv4`
//

#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


const char *string2 = " \
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! cameraundistort name=undist1 ! ximagesink \
";


gchar *
camera_serialize_undistort_settings (cv::Mat & cameraMatrix,
    cv::Mat & distCoeffs)
{
  cv::FileStorage fs (".xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE + cv::FileStorage::MEMORY);
  fs << "cameraMatrix" << cameraMatrix;
  fs << "distCoeffs" << distCoeffs;
  std::string buf = fs.releaseAndGetString ();

  return g_strdup (buf.c_str ());
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    float camera_matrix_data[9] = { 3.3860583405334381e+02, 0., 2.9082938038777263e+02, 0.,
    3.3860583405334381e+02, 1.5389814447354675e+02, 0., 0., 1. };

    cv::Mat camera_matrix = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, camera_matrix_data);

    float dist_coefficients_data[5] = {-7.3120392823523372e-01, 6.2624904277006888e-01,
    -1.0205399762451621e-02, 5.1857216532169093e-03,
    -2.0130033675444331e-01};

    cv::Mat dist_coefficients = cv::Mat(5, 1, CV_32F, dist_coefficients_data);

    gchar * dist = camera_serialize_undistort_settings(camera_matrix, dist_coefficients);

  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstElement *filesrc;
  GstMessage *msg;
  GstBus *bus;
  GError *error = NULL;

  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  pipeline = gst_parse_launch (string2, &error);



  if (!pipeline) {
    g_print ("Parse error: %s\n", error->message);
    exit (1);
  }

  // Feed in our settings
  filesrc = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (pipeline), "undist1");
  g_object_set (filesrc, "settings", dist, NULL);
  g_object_unref (filesrc);


  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);

  /* wait until we either get an EOS or an ERROR message. Note that in a real
   * program you would probably not use gst_bus_poll(), but rather set up an
   * async signal watch on the bus and run a main loop and connect to the
   * bus's signals to catch certain messages or all messages */
  msg = gst_bus_poll (bus, (GstMessageType) ( GST_MESSAGE_EOS | GST_MESSAGE_ERROR ), -1);

  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS: {
      g_print ("EOS\n");
      break;
    }
    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
      GError *err = NULL; /* error to show to users                 */
      gchar *dbg = NULL;  /* additional debug string for developers */

      gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &dbg);
      if (err) {
        g_printerr ("ERROR: %s\n", err->message);
        g_error_free (err);
      }
      if (dbg) {
        g_printerr ("[Debug details: %s]\n", dbg);
        g_free (dbg);
      }
    }
    default:
      g_printerr ("Unexpected message of type %d", GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg));
      break;
  }
  gst_message_unref (msg);

  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  gst_object_unref (bus);

  return 0;
}
```